# Can you capture the event of sending instant message from Yahoo Messenger and replace text using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, intercept, yahoo-messenger

I've just made a quick research about that but there is nothing about that in C#.
Is this a lost cause or it can be made?

Comment: You should elaborate more on what you are trying to do. Smells like you're trying to write a malware for now...

Comment: If there is a link in the message I want to delete it. Same for curse...

Answer (score 1):

As Yahoo Messenger is not an open source project, I have no idea about how sending message is implemented. First thing you should do is launching [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your machine to see how Yahoo Messenger works (which port is used, which protocol, data encryption...etc.).

When you have determined how the application works, you'll have to write some low level code that *intercepts* and *modifies* the bytes Yahoo Messenger sends. You'll probably have to write a driver, so it looks to me like a dead-end if your are using C#. And even using C/C++ or any langage usable to write drivers, it'll require a large amount of time/resources IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify behavior of an closed source application. The only thing i can think of is somehow goeing lower-level in the [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) model (Transport layer i.e.) and change values. This sounds like a bad idea.

Actually i even wonder whether that data is sent plain-text or that encryption etc. has been used. I wonder if you can actually change the message at all.

Comment: OSI model? Maybe you mean TCP/IP model/stack?

Comment: Yes. When you can not change the sources of the application, you can only change what is sends over the line. However, i think it is no good practise.  I also wonder about the use case of MariusM.

Comment: Use case: if there is a link in the message I want to delete it.